# phpMyAdmin too many warnings and redirection

Tags: phpmyadmin

On logging in, phpMyAdmin is giving too many warnings, and on clicking on databases or any other field, it is redirecting to the login page with the warning:

```
Warning in .\libraries\session.lib.php#20
 session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed

Backtrace

 .\libraries\session.lib.php#20: session_regenerate_id(boolean true)
 .\libraries\common.inc.php#637: PMA_secureSession()
 .\server_databases.php#15: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)
```

Comment: Could you please provide your phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL/MariaDB versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try with incognito mode.

Or

delete your browser cache and  cookies.
restart browser.
Login again .

Most probably It will solve your problem.